# How to convert values from certain keys of an array to numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array of objects

```
const mi_array = [{
  agrupacion: "Total país",
  col2015: '81.8',
  col2016: '86.4',
  col2017: '67.3',
  col2018: '70.8',
  col2019: '67.6'
},{
  agrupacion: "otra cosa",
  col2015: '90.8',
  col2016: '67.4',
  col2017: '39.3',
  col2018: '50.8',
  col2019: '95.6'
}];
```

I need to transform this into something like this:

```
const new_array = [{
  name: "Total país",
  data: [81.8, 86.4, 67.3, 70.8, 67.6]
}, {
  name: "otra cosa",
  data: [90.8, 67.4, 39.3, 50.8, 95.6]
}];
```

I tried this but since values on keys col2015 thru 2019 are all strings, it doesn't work as intended

```
const result = mi_array.map(e => ({
  name: e.agrupacion,
  data: Object.values(e).filter(e => typeof e == 'number')
}))

console.log(result)
```

output:

```
[{
  data: [],
  name: "Total país"
}, {
  data: [],
  name: "otra cosa"
}]
```

I know it will work if I can transform those values into numbers somehow so i tried to achieve that with this:

```
for(let key of Object.keys(mi_array))  mi_array[key] = +mi_array[key]

console.log(mi_array);
```

however my output is:

```
[NaN, NaN]
```

another attempt:

```
var result = Object.keys(mi_array).map(function(key) {
  return [Number(key), mi_array[key]];
}); 

console.log(result);
```

another failed output:

```
[[0, {
  agrupacion: "Total país",
  col2015: "81.8",
  col2016: "86.4",
  col2017: "67.3",
  col2018: "70.8",
  col2019: "67.6"
}], [1, {
  agrupacion: "otra cosa",
  col2015: "90.8",
  col2016: "67.4",
  col2017: "39.3",
  col2018: "50.8",
  col2019: "95.6"
}]]
```

Is there an efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could destructure `name` and take from the rest only the values as `data`, after mapping with `Number`.

This approach takes the original order of the object.

```js
const
    mi_array = [{ agrupacion: "Total país", col2015: '81.8', col2016: '86.4', col2017: '67.3', col2018: '70.8', col2019: '67.6' }, { agrupacion: "otra cosa", col2015: '90.8', col2016: '67.4', col2017: '39.3', col2018: '50.8', col2019: '95.6' }],
    result = mi_array.map(({ agrupacion: name, ...o }) => ({
        name,
        data: Object.values(o).map(Number)
    }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: All of the answers led to the right solution that I was looking for, so I'll pick the one with the less amount of code used, and the most efficient to me, thanks

Comment: @ChrisG hopefully it makes sense, too. I do like that it is sweet and to the point, but a little more detail in the answer would be nice. Otherwise I'll have to copy and replace!

Comment: Nina did not just pasted the solution and left it as that. A small explanation of what the approach does was good enough for me to understand how it works. Which is why I decided to go with that. Still I took my time to try all of your answers and upvoted everyone elses answers since the all got to the same result, just a different approach

Answer (score 1):

```
const new_array = [];

for(let i = 0; i < mi_array.length; ++i) {

  const new_obj = {"name":"", "data":[]};

  for(const key in mi_array[i]) {

    const num = Number(mi_array[i][key]);

    if(isNaN(num)) {
      new_obj.name = mi_array[i][key];
    } else {
      new_obj.data.push(num);
    }

  }

  new_array.push(new_obj);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use it.

First, map array and take properties `agrupacion` and rest props for map in `data` and convert to `Number`.

```js
const newArr = mi_array.map(({agrupacion, ...props})=> ({
    name:agrupacion,
  data: [...Object.values(props).map(value => Number(value))]
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const mi_array = [{
  agrupacion: "Total país",
  col2015: '81.8',
  col2016: '86.4',
  col2017: '67.3',
  col2018: '70.8',
  col2019: '67.6'
},{
  agrupacion: "otra cosa",
  col2015: '90.8',
  col2016: '67.4',
  col2017: '39.3',
  col2018: '50.8',
  col2019: '95.6'
}];

new_array = []
for (var i = 0; i < mi_array.length; i++)
{
    new_dict = {"Data": []}
    for (item in mi_array[i])
    {
      x = parseFloat(mi_array[i][item])
      if (!(!(!(x))))
      {
          new_dict["Name"] = mi_array[i][item]
      }
      else
      {
          new_dict["Data"].push(x);
      }
    }
    new_array.push(new_dict);
}
console.log(new_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. I wanted to update only those values in each object that can be converted.
Here how I resolved

```
 const changeStrValuesToIntInObj= chartData.data.map((temp) => {
        const updatedObject = {};
        for (const key in temp) {
          const value = temp[key];
          updatedObject[key] = !isNaN(Number(value)) ? parseFloat(value) : value;
        }
        return { ...temp, ...updatedObject };
      });
```